# Receiving emails via SendGrid

Tags: email, sendgrid

How do I use sendgrid to receive email and then be able to reply to that email from our domain? Like someone sends an email to contact@lessonshark.com and we reply via contact@lessonshark.com.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this [sample PHP application](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-parse-demo), the `parseListener.php` script in particular. It looks at the text of the email, rolls an arbitrary number of dice based on that text, and then responds to the requester with that many dice rolls.

In order to do something like this, you'll need to deploy that script somewhere accessible to the internet (a hosting company that supports PHP for example), update the code to use your SendGrid username and password, and then configure the [SendGrid Parse Webhook](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/parse-api-2/) to be pointed to the script, e.g. `http://example.com/webhooks/parseListener.php`

Comment: awesome thanks for the quick response, you guys must be watching stackoverflow all the time

Comment: +1 on @Brand's sentiments.  If you're looking for a javascript example, I have a pretty detailed one here https://github.com/theycallmeswift/playlist.sendgriddemos.com

Comment: mx.sendgrid is great, tks